# throw simple exception with message

Tags: java, exception

There is simple  way to throw exception with message in java ?
In the following method I check for types and if the type doesn't exist i want to throw message 
that the type is not supported ,what is the simplest way to do that ?

```
public static SwitchType<?> switchInput(final String typeName) {

    if (typeName.equals("java.lang.String")) {

    }
    else if (typeName.equals("Binary")) {

    }
    else if (typeName.equals("Decimal")) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Simplest way is to learn java Exception handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Exception Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a String as parameter:

```
        if (typeName.equals("java.lang.String")) {

        }
        else if (typeName.equals("Binary")) {

        }
        else if (typeName.equals("Decimal")) {

        }
        else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong type passed");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to handle an illegal argument is to throw [an `IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

```
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This type is not supported: " + typeName);
}
```

And try [not to return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168397/is-returning-null-after-exception-is-caught-bad-design) if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

this method cannot throw an exception really
because `typeName` in input parameter of function is a `String` already..